# Save List<T> in ApplicationSettings (C#)

Tags: c#

Как сохранять произвольный список в параметрах приложения (Visual Studio, C#)?
Например есть список произвольной длины, состоящий из объектов следующего типа:

```
public class ExeProgram
{

    public string Name{get; set;}
    public string Path{get; set;}
    public int Index{get;set;}
}

List<ExeProgram> programs;
```

Как такой список сохранять в стандартный user.config?
Везде описывается как сохранять простые типы в параметрах приложения. Про пользовательские типы информации мало. Вариант сериализации в файл с использованием XmlSerializer решен. Но интересует сохранение именно через стандартный механизм сохранения параметров System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager или ApplicationSettingsBase

Comment: Обычно программа только читает конфиг. Какой алгоритм работы с конфигом вы предполагаете?

Comment: По документации MS программа только читает app.exe.config, а user.config и читает и пишет. Алгоритм такой: программа из настроек считывает список объектов ExeProgram (список внешних программ), создает соответствующее количество ToolStripBottom в ToolStrip, для запуска этих программ. Пользователь в программе может изменить список этих программ. Измененный список сохраняется в user.config

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, убедитесь, что вы можете положить в Settings *один* экземпляр `ExeProgram`. Возможно, для этого нужно будеть сделать его сериализируемым.

Затем, в старых версиях Visual Studio был баг, в результате которого `List<T>` невозможно было положить в Settings. В [этом вопросе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24938228/276994) описан обходной путь: создайте настройку с произвольным типом, откройте файл `.settings` текстовым редактором, найдите нужный элемент и поменяйте вручную его тип (атрибут `Type`) с того, который вы смогли ввести, на `System.Collections.Generic.List&lt;<тут не забудьте правильный namespace>.ExeProgram&gt;`. `&lt;` и `&gt;` нужны из-за XML-формата.

Comment: Спасибо! Все получилось! Только тип кроме как в файле Settings.settings надо подправлять еще в файле Settings.Designer.cs, а то сбрасывается на string. Хотя может это потому, что я сейчас использую SharpDevelop

Comment: @МаратГайфуллин: Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0):

Использование `ApplicationSettingsBase` довольно простое: просто создайте настройку указанного вами типа - по умолчанию она будет сериализована в виде xml.

Comment: как? приведите пожалуйста пример или дайте ссылку. устал рыть интернет

Comment: Извиняюсь, я не понимаю проблему. Надо просто зайти в список настроек проекта и создать там настройку нужного типа. Я так понимаю из вашего вопроса, делать создавать настройку примитивного типа вы уже умеете. Делать тип совместимым с `XmlSerializer` - тоже. Что мешает создать настройку типа `List<ExeProgram>`?

Comment: UPD: и правда, что-то мешает. Точнее, мешает интерфейс, который не поддерживает шаблоны. Создайте класс-обертку над `List<ExeProgram>`.

Comment: Недавно перешел на Visual Studio C#, мешает отсутствие грамотной справки и своего опыта.

Comment: Что должно быть в классе-обертке над List<ExeProgram>?

Comment: Одно публичное свойство требуемого типа.