# Сериализация Item'ов

Tags: c#, сериализация

Подскажите, как сериализовать созданные Item'ы в панели, их текст, значение CheckBox и кнопку Delete, и дессериализовать при перезапуске программы? Понимаю, как сделать это с простым текстом или классом, а что делать с целым User Control'ом понятия не имею...[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Выберите подходящий формат (`JSON`(советую), `XML`), создайте некую модель, которая будет содержать в себе все необходимые поля и к ним привяжитесь (если WPF, то банальный Binding). При изменение, либо закрытие приложения делайте сериализацию в нужный формат. Ну и естественно при открытие приложение обратная десериализация из файла в модель.

Answer (score 2):

Сериализовать элементы управления полностью **не нужно**.

Сериализация данных на то и сериализация, что мы *преобразовываем* их в формат, удобный для чтения, отправки и записи.

На скриншоте я вижу, что вы собираетесь сериализовать список ваших дел. Что минимально нужно, чтобы представить одно дело? Описание дела и статус.

Значит пишите в JSON или подобный формат массив, один элемент которого выглядит так:

```
{description: "Meet with Sergey", status: false}
```

А дальше читаете ваш файлик, плодите нужное количество чекбоксов, пихаете их на панель и заполняете согласно содержимому файла.

Comment: А как мне это реализовать в коде?

Comment: @DocTor Берете JSON-библиотеку, создаете массив структур/обьектов с полями статуса и описания ToDo, складываете туда данные из ваших чекбоксов и сериализуете.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, постараюсь сделать

Answer (score 1):

Для сохранения состояния в .NET не нужно изобретать велосипед с сериализацией. Просто запишите ваши данные в Settings, и при следующем старте они автоматически восстановятся. (Картинки смотрите [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/502621/10105).)

Comment: А если несколько строк? Как их записать в Settings, а потом считать?

Comment: @DocTor: Ну положите в Settings не `string`, а `List<string>`.

Comment: @DocTor: Вот тут примеры: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/422380/10105, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/207616/10105, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/466102/10105